# How do I get the fireEvent method to work in IE8?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to submit a form using IEs fireEvent method.  Here's some simple test code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function fireSubmit () {
  if (document.createEventObject) {
        var event = document.createEventObject ();
    var fired = document.forms['fireForm'].fireEvent("onsubmit", event);
    alert("event fired: " + fired + "; event returnValue: " + event.returnValue);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button onmouseover="fireSubmit();">
      Hover to submit
  </button>

  <form name="fireForm" action="action.html" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the simple action.html that should get submitted:

```
<html>
<body>
<script>alert('submitted');</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I hover over the button, the event does get created and IE claims it was fired.  An alert pops up that says "event fired: true; event returnValue: **undefined**", but the action.html alert is never shown and the returnValue is never set contrary to what [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536423(v=vs.85).aspx) claims.  However, if I just click on the submit button, the form is actually submitted and the "submitted" dialog shows.

What am I doing wrong?  Am I misusing IE in some heinous way?

***edit***: Basically I'm trying to use the event model to catch problems down the line.  The following code using [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent) works fine in non-IE browsers for the same purpose:

```
    if (document.createEvent) {
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("submit", false, false);
        var returnValue = document.forms['fireForm'].dispatchEvent(event);          

        alert("event returnValue: " + returnValue);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents

> Note that manually firing an event does not generate the default action associated with that event. For example, manually firing a focus event does not cause the element to receive focus (you must use its focus method for that), **manually firing a submit event does not submit a form** (use the submit method), manually firing a key event does not cause that letter to appear in a focused text input, and manually firing a click event on a link does not cause the link to be activated, etc.

The fireEvent method won't submit your form; *it will trigger any event handlers attached to that event*. The form's submit method will submit the form.

Is this what you want to do?

```
function fireSubmit () {
    var fired = document.forms['fireForm'].submit();
    alert("event fired: " + fired + "; event returnValue: " + event.returnValue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  That's not exactly it though.  For one, the submit() method does not actually return a value to fired, and second I'm not sure how event.returnValue gets assigned in your example.  I added a working non-IE example to the question.